# ggplot - Plotting several sin functions on one graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I want to show graphically how the summation of two different sin curves looks like. 
So, I am trying to make a single graph that shows two different sin function and their sum. So, three curves on one graph.

How can I do it with ggplot layers?

I am defing two sin functions (y and z)

```
x <- seq(0, 16*pi, 0.01)
y <- 2*sin(3*(x-1))
z <- sin(x)
```

summing up the two curves:

```
t <- y + z
```

I can see the three separately with:

```
plot(x,y,type="l")
plot(x,z,type="l")
plot(x,t,type="l")
```

But how can I plot the three functions?

I tried this but it does not work

```
ggplot(x,
       qplot(y,x,geom="path", xlab="time", ylab="Sine wave") +
       qplot(z,x,geom="path", xlab="time", ylab="Sine wave"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Store everything in a `data.frame`, reshape from wide to long, and plot:

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(x = x, y = y, z = z, t = y + z) %>%
    pivot_longer(-x) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x, value, colour = name)) +
    geom_line()
```

[image]

---

### Sample data

```
x <- seq(0, 16*pi, 0.01)
y <- 2*sin(3*(x-1))
z <- sin(x)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get an error: could not find function "pivot_longer". I have already tried with tidyr, dplyr, tidyverse, data.table and it does work. How to make it work? THANKS

Comment: @RonSlavaGrodko You need to update `tidyr`; `pivot_longer` was introduced in version `1.0.0` (the current CRAN version is `1.0.2`) and replaced `gather`. The old version would be `gather(name, value, -x)`.